# Magento custom option value and option title store when the user add product to cart

Tags: php, html, magento

I want to store values in session as like below

```
option => array (
   ['option_display] => array(
        'color' => 'white',
         'RAM'  => '3gb'
         ),
   ['option_details'] => array (
         '5' => '3'
         '6' => '5'
         ) );
```

Above code is the options for product to choose color and RAM are the titles for the options and their values, In option_details array contains id for the above options.
The option display array values are need to display in front end and option details array are need to store in db.

My code is

```
case 'radio':
            echo $value->getTitle();
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_display['.$value->getTitle().']" id="option_display_'.$value->getTitle().'" />';
            echo '<p class="'.(($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? 'required' : '').'">'.(($value->getIsRequire() == 1) ? '*Required Field' : '').'</p>';
            foreach ($option as $values) {
                echo '<div>
                        <input type="radio" name="option_value['.$value->getOptionId().']" value ="'.$values['option_type_id'].'" id="option_value_'.$value->getOptionId().'" />'.$values['title'].'
                    </div>';
            }
            break;
```

If i select the values the option details are coming but option display array has only option titles no values are coming because i cant select values in hidden field
My ouput array is

```
option => array (['option_display] => array(
    [color] => 
     [RAM]  => 
     ),       ['option_details'] => array (
     [5] => '3'
     [6] => '5'
     ) );
```

How can get the values in both array when user selects the option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update value as user select the options ,

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_display['.$value->getTitle().']" id="option_display_'.$value->getTitle().'" />';
```

To

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_display['.$value->getTitle().']" id="option_display_'.$value->getTitle().'" value="user_selected_value" />';
```

Comment: if its text box means what should i do..?

Comment: same as option,
You have to create onchange event on that text fields and update display inputs as well.